# Retrieving a value from a textbox and using it in a link

Tags: javascript, php

I have a link to which i need to retrieve a value from a text field. The link is as follows

```
http://cloudagent.in/CAServices/AgentManualDial.php?username=Versa_Drivers&api_key=KK11936cc1f4b65e9cee0d7022edaa0b89&**customerNumber=30xxxx**&uui=Click2Call&skill=Versa_Drivers&did=914439942522
```

In the above link i need to retrieve the customerNumber=30xxx from a text field. Kindly help, and Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take it's value using jquery and then parse URL.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander has said, use js or jquery to get the value of the text field, then use it to parse the value in the dynamically generated url. You can use an OnChange event listener on the text field for the cust no to invoke the URL to be updated in real time. That's the best we can do without any source. :)

Good luck :)